# Is it impolite to send holiday wishes to one's advisor?

Tags: advisor

I am an international student in the US. Whenever I wish my PhD advisor on holidays (over email), like on Christmas or on Thanksgiving, he never responds.

Is it impolite to wish your advisor on such holidays? Is it common to maintain professional boundaries with one's student by not responding to such holiday wishes? I am not sure what the etiquette is here.

Comment: Why not say it in person?

Comment: devil's advocate: maybe they work all the holidays, so they do not really care about your wishes.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's impolite. However, I don't think it is particularly common.

In the absence of any other information, I would interpret "no response" as neutral, meaning the person read the email, but didn't feel it required a response. I would say it's likely that the person either appreciated it but had to move on quickly to other things, or else did not care one way or the other; I think it is unlikely that they thought something negative about you. I can understand how a non-response might feel cold to you, especially if you were expecting them to send a message in return. But, people are busy, especially around holidays, and you generally shouldn't expect responses to non-work-related emails from people you have a purely professional relationship with. That's not to say that you can't have a more personal relationship with your advisor, but that will depend on you and your advisor and isn't required for a successful advisor-advisee relationship.

As was suggested in the comments, I think it's very likely that if you wished the person happy holidays face-to-face, they would appreciate it and respond in kind.

One caveat is that not everyone celebrates Christmas. So it is possible to commit a faux pas by wishing Merry Christmas to someone who does not celebrate it; generally "Happy Holidays" is safer. However, I think most people would likely treat that as a well-intentioned mistake if you did that, or else gently correct you if it mattered to them. (And, on the other hand, I have wished "Happy Holidays" to a professor who corrected me with "MERRY CHRISTMAS", so sometimes even when you try to be careful, you can't win :-))

Answer (score 2):

No its not impolite all. I wish everyone in my research group a happy Christmas, and they all wish me the same. I also generally intend to send a happy Christmas message to my undergrad tutees, even if i don't always remember.

It is generally considered polite to respond to such a message. However i wouldn't expect a reply on the holiday day(s) itself - holidays are about resting and if your advisor has any sense, they won't be checking their messages!

I would see failing to get any reply an impoliteness, but a minor one. There are much worse things an advisor can do than fail to acknowledge holiday wishes.